# Add record to table with FK

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a table UserStoreName,

Columns are :

int Id

string UserNameId (as a FK of the table AspNetUsers (Column Id))

sring StoreName

I have a page AddStore, a very simple page where user just enter the store name into the StoreName Field.
I already know the UserNameId, i'm taking it from the User.
So when user populate the storeName field and click submit i just need to add a record to the table UserStoreName.
sounds easy.
when i click submit the AddStore function from the controller is giving me ModelState.IsValid = false.
reason for that is cause userNameId is a required field.
i want to populate that field in the AddStore
function but when we get there the modelState is already invalid because of a required field in userStoreNameId enter code here
Here is the AddStore in case it will help :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult AddStore(UserStoreName userStoreName)
{
    userStoreName.UserNameId =
    (_unitOfWork.ApplicationUser.GetAll().Where(q => q.UserName == User.Identity.Name).Select(q => q.Id)).FirstOrDefault();
    userStoreName.UserName = User.Identity.Name;
    userStoreName.IsAdminStore = false;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
            _unitOfWork.UserStoreName.Add(userStoreName);
        
        _unitOfWork.Save();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    return View(userStoreName);
}
```

Any idea what am i doing wrong? new to asp.net core mvc, its my first project.
Thanks :)
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the UserNameId field is required, it must be supplied to pass model validation.

There are two ways around this. First, you could create a View Model, with just the fields you plan on actually submitting, and use it in place of the userStoreName variable. Then in the controller action, you can just instantiate a new UserStoreName object, and fill out the fields.

Alternatively, you could pass the UserNameId variable to the view, and populate the model client side using a hidden field, so it passes validation when returned to the controller. Hidden fields can potentially have their values edited client-side, however, so it may be worth checking the value again server side, especially if there are any security implications.

Comment: Thanks! passed the variable using ViewBag and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys can be nullable so just make sure the `UserNameId` field is not marked with the "[Required]" Data Annotation in your model.

You'll also need to make sure that the column is nullable on the `UserStoreName` table to match the model otherwise it'll cause problems if your model is different from its underlying table.

Just a small suggestion also, I wouldn't foreign key on strings, I would change your model foreign key to an int, and make sure that the column in the table it's related to is also an int. It's a lot safer to do so, especially if you're dealing with IDENTITY columns.

If there is anything wrong with the reference, an exception will throw when the code tries to save your change, usually because the value it has in the FK reference cannot be found in the related table.